# Crafter CMS 2.5.x - Reindex Preview Context

Tags: crafter-cms

I followed the instructions at
http://docs.craftercms.org/en/2.5/system-administrators/reindexing-content.html
Everything worked fine but I'm not able to re-index the context on preview, when I select the beans in the preview context I got a message saying "No processor found by name: XXXX"

I'm working with Alfresco as my content repository